# Syntax error when add user in sudoers

Tags: sudo

I am going to execute all commands without sudo and entering password.So I added:

```
    user All = NOPASSWD : ALL
```

But it shows me syntax error.

Comment: It is not a good idea to do that.

Comment: really? what is the good idea?

Comment: The good idea is to enter password for sudo commands.

Comment: I do not need password for executing commands

Comment: @HananeGhobadi Removing password verification for any sudo-required command has potential security risk. If your username and password ever gets stolen, an attacker can use your machine as a bot for Distributed Denial of Service attack, or worse. But if you want FBI coming at your door, by all means, go ahead and do that

Comment: Also malware can access system files if they are not password protected.

Comment: You are right but it is just test. I am going to test something in virtual machine.

Answer (score 1):

type `sudo visudo` in a terminal and place to the end of the file:

```
user ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

Save the file and start a test with:

```
service ssh restart
```

Comment: When I save it I got syntax error

Comment: Excuse me, but why `service ssh restart` ?

Comment: I added this line to User privilege specification. Is it right?

Answer (score 0):

I changed:

`Sudo All=(All:All) All`

to

```
Sudo All=(All) NOPASSWD: All
```

so it does not need to enter password. Thanks Guys